# javascript replace is replacing nested words

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, replace

I am creating a google chrome extension that messes with the words on whatever website you are reading, but I am having trouble with this section of code specifically.

```
if(Math.random() > 0.0){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/he/g, "it");}
```

Unfortunately it is also working on the word that is inside inside another. For example: when it comes across the word "the", it turns 'he' into it, unfortunately making it says "tit".
how can I change my code to avoid this?

Comment: Worth mentioning that the method you're replacing text is awful. Should you just be changing text nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.replace(/\bhe\b/g, "it")
```

`\b` matches the word boundary, so it will only replace a single word `he`, not `he` as a part of another word