# Is there way to change a substring in js?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like:

```
def definition():
```

I want to change word def (for example), every instance of word def but not the "def"s that are part of other words
like this

```
console.log("def definition():".specialReplace("def", "abc"));
```

and result should be

```
abc definition():
```

not

```
abc abcinition():
```

Comment: @sp00m - I think you mean `\bdef\b`.

Comment: I would probably join your string into a space-delimited array and replace any exact matches in the array elements.

Comment: Is this JavaScript or Python you are asking this for?

Comment: @mplungjan Javascript, i just gave a random stirng to replace def when its a single word not connected to other letters such as defintion

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think you didnt understood what i meant. I wanted a function that will just change word def in abc, when "def" is single like"def", but not "definition". normal replace function doesn't help

Comment: `"def definition():".replace(/def/,"abc")` will only replace the first def

Comment: @ICYCounter-StrikeandLeague - If you say "first" it's reasonable to assume you mean the first. But replacing just words and not sequences within words is also **very** well-covered here. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554776/javascript-replace-is-replacing-nested-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or [`String#replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
const specialReplace = (str) => str.replaceAll(/\bdef\b/g, 'abc')
console.log(specialReplace("def definition")) // abc definition
console.log(specialReplace("def definition def")) // abc definition abc
```

In the regular expression, `\b` is a [boundary type assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) that matches any word boundary, such as between a letter and a space.

Note that the same sequence `\b` is also used inside character class regular expression positions (`[\b]`), to match the backspace character.

Comment: Surely "replacing just a word" is already covered by **multiple** previous questions and answers? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554776/javascript-replace-is-replacing-nested-words